# How can we load an object anytime we want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question. I'm wondering if someone tell me how can i load an object when i want, with jquery.. For example if i click a button, an image be loaded..my meaning is not to show an object, my meaning is that the image don't download until the button be clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an image tag in your HTML with an empty `src` attribute, then add this jQuery code, modifying selectors as needed.

```
$(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        $("#myImage").attr("src", "myimgsrc.jpg");
    });
});
```